# Trouble with CKFinder + Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, ckfinder

I did everything according to points 1-5 as indicated in the Readme.MD
https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package#configuring-authentication

On site authors say: `At this point you should see the connector JSON response after navigating to the <APP BASE URL>/ckfinder/connector?command=Init address. Authentication for CKFinder is not configured yet, so you will see an error response saying that CKFinder is not enabled`

I opened link

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ckfinder/connector?command=Init
```

And have JSON error:

> {"error":{"number":110,"message":"Unknown error."}}

Can someone help me? How to find reason of trouble? i google many sites and there is no desicion

Answer (score 1):

Are you using PHP 8+?

For me the issue was a deprecated line in the package itself.

I fixed this error by changing `vendor\ckfinder\ckfinder-laravel-package\_connector\ArgumentResolver.php` `line 65`

from

```php
if ($reflectionClass = $param->getClass()) {
```

to

```php
if ($reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($param->getType()->getName())) {
```

because `getClass()` is deprecated in PHP 8.0.3, It works fine for me now.

**Note: Do keep in mind that it's not good to change things inside the vendor folder!**